# Java Eclipse - build application)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am really fresh at Java.

I'have created new Java Project. Created package Main and Main.java class Main in this package.

```
package Main;

public class Main {
     public Main(String[] argv) {
          System.out.println("Helloworld.");
     }
}
```

When I try to run it - Eclipse gives an error: Selection does not contain applet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create/run-as applet.

Some other notes:

**1)** `main` methods must be declared as follows in order to be recognized as an entry point:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    // Your code here
}
```

The name of the parameter is arbitrary, but usually `argv` or `args`.

**2)** Packages should be named in all-lower case. Method names should start with a lower-case letter.