# Java processing applet not running

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, processing

When I try to run my java code for processing it shows an error "selection does not contain applet".  This is how I am supposed to run my code.

Here is my code:

```
package proccesing;
import processing.core.*;

public class proccesing extends PApplet {

    public void setup() {
        background(100,100);
    }

    public void draw() {
        line(0,0,0,100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Eclipse - build application)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142627/java-eclipse-build-application)

Answer (score 1):

As of Processing 3, `PApplet` no longer extends `Applet`. In other words, you can't deploy as an applet anymore.

You could try using the Applet exporting tool, but you're much better off using Processing.js to deploy as JavaScript. Applets are pretty much dead and shouldn't really be used anymore.